# Need free ssl certificate because google chrome doesn't support webcam without https

Tags: ssl-certificate

The new version of google chrome doesn't allow using webcam without https :

> getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this
>   feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure
>   origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

So I need a free ssl certificate (or cheap ssl certificate) for my web application. Openssl doesn't suit me because browsers display warning message when the ssl certificate is self-signed.

An idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use https://letsencrypt.org/ to get a free valid ssl certificate recognized by your mobile phone and by your web browser

Comment: it's not free. They are asking mandatory to donate at least 10$.

Comment: it's free. Check again. I know I use it, I dont pay, its free.

Answer (score 0):

I use cloudflare.com Origin Certificate. It is pretty good.